# Visual D: project import paths

Tags: d, visual-d

How can I add an import path **to a project** in Visual D?

I've found how it can be done for every project (Tools->Options->Visual D Settings->DMD Directories).

How can I do this for projects individually?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how!

(I am using Visual Studio 2017)

In your Solution Explorer right click on the project you want and click "Properties".
Navigate to "Configuration Properties">"Compiler">"General" 
Use the "Additional Import Paths".

For me when I added a path it put a double quote (") at the beginning of the path, but it did not work until I put the closing quote at the end.